# Error comparing alias column in DQL query's CASE statement

Tags: mysql, symfony, dql

I'm trying to convert very complex MySQL query to DQL. The main problem is coming when I'm trying to use or compare the alias column with name **total_days**, here is the example **DQL query**:

```
SELECT (1+1) AS total_days,
(CASE WHEN (total_days = 1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS test 
FROM AppBundle:PeriodPrices
```

the query is more complex, but I keep it simple here only for the testing purposes! Here is the exception:

```
An exception occurred while executing '
SELECT (1 + 1) AS sclr0, 
(CASE WHEN (sclr0 = 1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS sclr1 
FROM PeriodPrices p0_':

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'sclr0' in 'field list'
```

this is the converted DQL to SQL query by Symfony framework, as I can see the alias field sclr0 is not visible in the CASE statement.

Note, if I'm using IF STATEMENT the query is working:

```
SELECT 
(1+1) AS total_days, 
IF( (SELECT total_days ) = 2, 1, 0) AS test
```

**The result:**

```
total_days    test  
2             1
```

Comment: You can't use alias in  others column select and where operation ..  only un query and gorup by

Comment: Why this is working? SELECT 
 (1+1) AS total_days, 
 IF( (SELECT total_days ) = 2, 1, 0) AS test